# using GROUP, STUFF and CONTAINS on same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    callTrackingId, 
    count(id) AS orders,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+ reviewStatus FROM ct_callOrder WHERE callTRackingId=co.callTrackingId GROUP BY reviewStatus FOR XML PATH(''))  ,  1 , 1 , '' ) as status
FROM ct_callorder co with (nolock)
WHERE CONTAINS(status, 'NEEDS_REVIEW')
GROUP BY callTrackingId
ORDER BY callTrackinIid ASC
```

I have a table with several rows and some of them have the same callTrackingId and i want a count of how many of those rows have the same trackingid. Also I need to be able to filter it based on if at least one of the statuses is equal to what I'm looking for. I managed to get all the statuses in a list but then when I try to filter it with a where contains I get an error. Im guessing its because that list might be created after the where clause is called. Any ideas on how i can filter it?

data sample:

`callTrackingId | reviewStatus
1 | NEEDS_REVIEW
1 | APPROVED
2 | APPROVED`

So if I filter it by NEEDS_REVIEW then I should get

```
callTrackingId | count
1 | 2
```

If filter by APPROVED then I should get

```
callTrackingId | count
1 | 2
2 | 1
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

PS: DB is MSSQL 20xx

Comment: The version can be pretty important..."MSSQL 20xx" is which version?

Comment: Oh I see what you are trying to do. That isn't going to work. You can't reference column aliases in the `where` and `contains` is a full text index function. Not something that searches arbitrary comma delimited lists.

Comment: Seems like a conditional `SUM()` would make far more sense than this.

Comment: I also tried using a subquery but then it complained about the orderby in a subquery with:ERROR: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions,
derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions,
unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
Error Code:
1033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` to filter based on an aggregation, in this case a conditional `SUM()` using `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    callTrackingId, 
    count(callTrackingId) AS orders
FROM Table1 co
GROUP BY callTrackingId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN reviewStatus = 'NEEDS_REVIEW' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ac0d/6/0)